# $5 \nmid 2^{n}-1$ when $n$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I want to prove that $$5 \nmid 2^{n}-1$$ where $n$ is odd.

I used Fermat's little theorem, which says $2^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, because $n$ is odd then $4 \nmid n$ , so it is done.

can you check it and say that my proof is right or wrong.

thanks.

Comment: $4 \nmid 2$, 2 is not odd.

Comment: Take care. That same argument would say $5\not\mid 6^n-1$ when $n$ is odd...

Comment: @Rol I took that to mean "$4\not\mid n$ *since* $n$ is odd." (Since $n$ is odd is the assumption of the question, OP is not trying to prove it.) It is poorly phrased, however.

Comment: Having $2^4\equiv 1\pmod 5, 4\nmid n$ is not enough to claim that $2^n\not\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, though it is enough if you first show that $4$ is indeed the least integer $m$ such that $2^m\equiv 1\pmod{5}$. More generally, the least integer $k$ such that $a^k\equiv 1\pmod {l}$ divides any other $h$ such that $a^h\equiv 1\pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $n=2k+1~,~k\geq 0$ since $n$ is odd. Now,

$$2^n=2^{2k+1}=2\cdot 4^k\equiv 2\cdot (-1)^k\equiv \begin{cases}2~,~k\textrm{ is even}\\ 3~,~k\textrm{ is odd}\end{cases}\pmod{5}$$

$$2^n-1=2^{2k+1}-1\equiv\begin{cases}1~,~k\textrm{ is even}\\ 2~,~k\textrm{ is odd}\end{cases}\pmod5\implies 2^n-1\not\equiv 0\pmod{5}~\forall~\textrm{odd }n$$

$$\therefore\quad 5\not\mid 2^n-1~\forall~\textrm{odd }n$$

---

This can also be done by induction, but the approach using modular arithmetic is the easiest.

Comment: if we change mod 5 to mod 11,how we can show it?in this way it seems we can't.

Comment: @kpax, I think we can use induction for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you observe the first few odd powers of 2, you can infer that last digit of all odd powers of 2 is either 2 or 8.

$2^1=2,2^3=8, 2^5=32, 2^7=128,...$

Hence $$\quad 5\not\mid 2^n-1~\forall~\textrm{odd }n$$

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ 5\!:\,\ 2^{1+2j}\equiv 2(4^j)\equiv 2(-1)^j\equiv \pm2 \not\equiv 1$